# passing unmanaged pointer field contained in managed class to unmanaged code

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I have a managed class which contains unmanaged class pointer:

```
class Managed { public IntPtr ptr; };
```

c++ function which takes a pointer as parameter:

```
void foo(void *ptr);
```

should i pin this Managed object before calling the unmanaged function?

calling code:

```
Managed obj = new Managed;
foo(obj.ptr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you'd need to pin it - even if the GC moves `obj` itself, the value of `obj.ptr` shouldn't be affected - and `obj.ptr` is passed to your C++ code by value, so it's not like the C++ code can try to change the contents of `obj`.